# Value of tokens

Tags: php

I would like to understand what tokens really mean in PHP.

The token of the syntax `__LINE__` is `T_LINE`.

`var_dump(__LINE__)` returns **int(1)** (in my case, because the code is on the first line).

`var_dump(T_LINE)` returns **int(370)**. What does that number mean? And why 370?

Comment: Have you read this? http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Right; as per the manual included above: *"This means that the concrete value of a token may change between two PHP versions."* - I get back "372".

Comment: To FFN's point: https://3v4l.org/12OT8